# How to get img url from api which is key based in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm using angular 5. I write bellow `http.get` method to get data from api in angular 5. I want to get the url of image to use this in my slider.

```
getImages(){
    this.httpclient.get('blabla/banner.php').subscribe((result) => {
    this.images = result;
    console.log(this.images);
})
}
```

but I'm getting data from api which id based below is my response

```
{  
   status:"success",
   …
}img:[  
   {  
      id:"1",
      banner:"/upload/img.jpg"
   },
   …
]0:{  
   id:"1",
   banner:"pload/img.jpg"
}1:{  
   id:"2",
   banner:"load/img2.jpg"
}2:{  
   id:"3",
   banner:"/admin/upload/img3.jpg"
}status:"success"
```

this my html template. I don't know is this right or wrong.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <button ></button>
            <li   data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active" *ngFor="let image of images">
              <img src="{{image.banner}}">
            </div>

         <!--    <div class="item">
              <img src="http://asianstylemagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/housefull-1.jpg" alt="Chicago">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://www.artsfon.com/large/201705/97685.jpg" alt="New York">
            </div>
          </div> -->

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting this after using `result.img`
[image]

I'm beginner to angular please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please let me know before downvoting
 what is not understanding.

Comment: How do you want to display these images? You should also share your template

Comment: I want to use this images in my slider for that m using *ngFor in my html

Comment: To get the img array of objects, you should use `this.images = result.img` in your getImages method. Please share that *ngFor template part.

Comment: @standby954 see i edited

Comment: Try to edit that part what I mentioned in your `getImages()` method.

Comment: when i adding .img after result it showing property 'img' does not exist ob type object.

Comment: What `console.log()` prints out the console?

Comment: in console I'm getting data of img

Comment: Try that `subscribe((result : any) => this.images = result.img)`

Comment: @David used..but got same data in console

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the data from console.log, after making the changes ?

Comment: yes..let post console.log

Comment: @David see i edited

Comment: So what's the issue now? It looks ok

Comment: but image not comming in html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167540/discussion-between-david-and-sagar-kodte).

Comment: got images..but slider is not working because active class is need to be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you get the correct data

```
getImages(){
    this.httpclient.get('blabla/banner.php').subscribe((result : any) => {
    this.images = result.img;
})
}
```

Also, in your carrousel, you need to make sure that only one item is active at the beginning (for now, all items have the `active` class)

```
<div class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': i==0}" *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
```

Answer (score 2):

In ts take the object as given below,

```
getImages(){
this.httpclient.get('blabla/banner.php').subscribe((result) => {
this.images = result.img; // store the img array in this.images
 })
}
```

The images variable will have the img array.
Now go to your template and use *ngFor

Example:-

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images">
   <img src="{{image.banner}}" alt="banners">
</div>
```

image in ngFor will iterate through your array  img and get all the urls.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks..got images in html..but active class should be there if i keep active class for div it's adding for both 3 divs.so how can i make it dyanamic